# Should I delete my answer which didn't receive any vote and isn't accepted?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, deleted-answers

I have given some answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28009280/3841803) which haven't been upvoted or accepted, and also it was answered months back. According to me it means my answer didn't help anybody so should I delete it.

Sorry for the stupid question just want to know if it would be a good approach to delete the answer or not.

Note: I got an upvote for the above link answer after I posted this question.Its not like I want some attention for my answer I dont need an upvote unless it helps someone there are many more answer of me like that I wolud be more thankful people will tell me what should I do in novote answer case instead of upvoting my upvoting those answer now.

Comment: I know that is very annoying. I would leave it for now(you can delete anytime), users that ask questions and do not respond goes against how this site works.

Comment: I have so many answers where the OP just never comes back and answer just sits there forever. But still If you think the answer is valuable, **leave** it, as it could be very useful to the next visitor !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you think the answer is of positive value, then keep it around.

If you feel that the answer is actively harmful, and that future readers would be better off not seeing your answer than being able to read it, then delete it.

You can use the opinions of others to help inform you, and to realize your mistakes or to realize that something that you thought was of value was not in fact of value, but if you are confident that your post really is of value, despite what other people think of it, then you shouldn't delete it.

Comment: There's a third one: If you think your answer doesn't add *any* value over the other ones there, you might just remove it. Keep in mind that sometimes simply using different words might be useful.

Comment: @Deduplicator If it's not adding any value, then it's actively harmful in that it's wasting the time of anyone that reads it.  Wasting people's time is actively harmful.  If readers of your answer would rather have that minute of their life back than have read your answer, then you are making the world a (very, very slightly) better place by deleting it.

Comment: Well, it's a question of degree. Wasting time isn't very "active", and when I see "harmful", I expect a bit more punch to it, most of the time.

Comment: Why does the system limit the number of answers that can be deleted to 5 per day?

Comment: @I.K. To prevent people from deleting good content out of spite.

Answer (score 5):

> According to me it means my answer didn't help anybody so should I delete it.

With no votes or comments on either answer, there's no way to conclude that it wasn't helpful. The question currently has 32 views. It could be that the people who saw it didn't have SO accounts, didn't have enough rep to up-vote or comment, or just didn't leave votes or comments for other reasons (like getting distracted and forgetting to come back, weren't in a position to test if your solution worked, etc.). You can't assume anyone found your answer wrong; it's not like it has down-votes or negative comments.

The lack of activity on your answer probably has more to do with the frequency of the problem described than any problem with your answer.

I agree with Servy that you should leave it up unless the answer is harmful. I don't think there's enough information to conclude it's not helpful. I don't know why the Asker never up-voted or accepted an answer, but it happens.